# Excel 2010. Automatically run macro from file with xlsx extension

Tags: vba, excel

I work with system, which automatically reads excel file, insets some date and sends to e-mail.
It works only with xlsx extension. 
I need, that sending file have some format (borders and filling), so I would like to use macro.
How can I do, that  macros automatically run  from file with xlsx extension? Can I store macro in Person.xlsm file and run it when it is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, macros cannot be saved in a .xlsx file.  You can however use `Workbooks.Open("filepath.xlsx")` to open and edit another workbook from a .xlsm workbook.  That is the way you should approach it.